# SQL If A Then B Else C

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute the following:

```
Declare @Customers nvarchar(MAX) = '15000, 15011'
--Declare @Customers nvarchar(MAX) = NULL


--IF A THEN B ELSE C
--((Not A) or B) AND (A or C)

SELECT SD.CustomerNumber, SD.CustomerName,
  CASE WHEN F.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasDiscount
From [dbo].[SubscriberDetails] As SD
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FamilyCustomer] F
    On F.CustomerNumber = SD.CustomerNumber
WHERE
((NOT @Customers IS NULL) OR F.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL) AND (@Customers IS NULL OR SD.CustomerNumber IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.iter$ListToTable(@Customers)))
```

What I'm trying to do is pass in a string of comma seperated values "15000,15011,16000..." OR NULL into @Customers param.  I'm using a function from [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV) that takes in a string
Then in my stored proc I want to check:

```
If Customers is Null then: 
   F.CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL
Else (@Customsers is not null Therefor)
   SELECT * FROM dbo.iter$ListToTable(@Customers)
```

Everything works fine If @Customers is passed at least one value, but I get `"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'number', table '@tbl'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." when passing in null`

((Not A) or B) AND (A or C) is taken from [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx)

What am i doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: I'm using a function that takes in a string (comma separated). I DON"T want to execute the function if @Customers is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `OR` in SQL is not short-circuiting, so `null` gets passed to `iter$ListToTable`.  I think the cleanest solution is to change the function to accept a `null` input.

Another option would be to use a table valiable within this sproc:

```
DECLARE @temp_Customers TABLE (@cust int)

IF (@Customers IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @temp_Custoers
 SELECT * FROM dbo.iter$ListToTable(@Customers)
END
```

and change your select to:

```
... AND (@Customers IS NULL OR SD.CustomerNumber IN (SELECT @cust FROM @temp_Customers))
```